# Java conditional loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to loop on an object, until a condition is met.

For example:

```
Input input = new inputFile(fileName);
input.nextMove();  // returns the next line - EOF returns null
```

So I want to do something like:

```
for (int[] move = input.nextMove(); move != null) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(move));
}
```

I.E. loop until the end of file.

Question

What's the best way to loop over the object?

Comment: For starters, for-loops have 3 components. That means two semi-colons. Each component is allowed to be blank.

Comment: Unrelated: class names should go CamelCase, so **I**nputFile ;-) ... it also feels a bit weird that an array of ints represents a *Move*. Probably that thing could be its own class....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a typical [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Iterator.html) pattern

```
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    T element = iterator.next();
}
```

which, for your case, can be adjusted to

```
int[] move;
while((move = input.nextMove()) != null) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(move));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do

```
int[] line;
while ((line = input.nextMove()) != null) { ... }
```

assuming that `nextMove()` returns an `int[]`.

This construct assigns the result of `nextMove()` to `line`, which is then available in the `while` body. You see here that such an assignment can be used as value-producing expression, and hence this can be compared. In this case, the loop breaks if `line` is `null`.

Comment: You can't do `int[] line` in a while expression. You need to declare it before. See Andrew's answer.

Comment: No problem. I made the same mistake actually but I pasted it into my IDE before posting an answer and realised my error!